# How do I have setinterval help me dynamically update multiple progress bars with a for loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, django-templates, setinterval

I'm trying to update multiple progress bars at once on a Django template, but what I find is that it only updates that last one. I'm not sure why the for loop here isn't working. Can anyone provide any guidance. Thank you in advance.

I pull in the values that I need from the HTML into objects. From there I use a for loop to adjust the width of the progress bar dynamically, but it's only responding to the last div to go through the for loop.

```
   var a = 0;

var counts = []

// Nestling relevant values in objects for for loop

var five = {
    bar: document.getElementById("fivesBar"),
    quantity: $("#fivesGiven").text()
}

var four = {
    bar: document.getElementById("foursBar"),
    quantity: $("#foursGiven").text()
}

var three = {
    bar: document.getElementById("threesBar"),
    quantity: $("#threesGiven").text()
}

var two = {
    bar: document.getElementById("twosBar"),
    quantity: $("#twosGiven").text()
}

var one = {
    bar: document.getElementById("onesBar"),
    quantity: $("#onesGiven").text()
}

counts.push(one, two, three, four, five);
console.log("Checking the list for counts:", counts);

// Grabbing percent complete to dynamically complete the progress bar
$(document).ready(function () {


    for (b = 0; b < counts.length; b++) {


        quantity = counts[b].quantity;
        console.log(quantity);
        quantity = parseInt(quantity)
        bar = counts[b].bar;

        if (a === 0) {
      
            var width = 0;
            var run = setInterval(fillratings, 5);

            function fillratings() {
        
                if (width === quantity) {
                    clearInterval(run);
                    a = 0;
                } else {
                    width++;
                    bar.style.width = width + "%";
                    console.log(width);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I believe your problem is that you declare `quantity` and `bar` without a keyword, which makes them global variables, and the loop will override previous value on each iteration, and once your interval-function triggers, it only has the last value to work with.  So, try `let quantity  = counts[b].quantity;` and `let bar = counts[b].bar;`. I think that should fix it, but there might be some other shenanigans going on here as well... (sorry for not taking the time to test)

Comment: I also think `var width` and `var run`  gets hoisted to outside the loop. You could try with a `let run = ...`, (instead of var)

Comment: THAT WORKED! Thank you so much!! I'm still trying to get the hang of when to use var vs. let. I really appreciate it! THANK YOU!!! @ippi

Comment: The rule is pretty simple: never use var.  (I don't even think it's subjective at this point)